# Does the vault.profile-separator for vault resent the precedence of reading properties?

Tags: spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I have a spring boot config server with native and vault back-ends.

I have set up a "cloud" profile for an app "my-app" so I have a property file "my-app-cloud.properties" and a vault entry "my-app,cloud". Both contain a property named `rs.allowOrigin`:

- `rs.allowOrigin=http://example.com` in my-app-cloud.properties and
- `rs.allowOrigin=http://localhost:4200` in the vault.

In this case, my-app's property will be have the value "http://localhost:4200", as it should.

If I set `spring.cloud.config.server.vault.profile-separator=/` and create a secret "my-app/cloud" with the content `rs.allowOrigin=http://localhost:4200`, then my-app's property is "http://example.com".

Is this a normal behaviour?

I'm using spring-boot 2.7.12.